# Boot Reciever never being called after boot but RecieverHandler is, and with data?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I have read that when you reboot with Android all of your AlarmManagers are deleted and they need to be remade. So I created a BootReciever class that will restart all my alarms by calling a WakefulIntentService like so:-

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.v("MessageDelay", "Reboot message Recieved");

        try {

            WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, BootSetter.class);    


            } catch (Exception e) {
             Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             e.printStackTrace();

            }

    }
 }
```

In the Manifest I declared it and put an intent filter so it only runs when the boot is completed like so:-

```
  <receiver android:name=".BootReciever">
         <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
         </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Now after tearing my hair out trying to fix an issue with this not working as intented, I have come to realise that my BootReciever class is not being called after a boot as it should be. Instead my other class named RecieverHandler is being called for everything. What’s more puzzling is the Intent passed to my RecieverHandler on startup actually has valid data that can be used without error.

My RecieverHandler looks like this:-

```
public class RecieverHandler extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {

        try {

             Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

             Log.v("MessageDelay", "RecieverHandler is doing boot jobs");

             Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, MessageDispatcher.class);
             newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            // newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG);
             //context.startService(newIntent);
             WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, newIntent);    


            } catch (Exception e) {
             Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             e.printStackTrace();

            }


    }
}
```

It is declared in the manifest like so:

```
<receiver android:name=".RecieverHandler">
        </receiver>
```

While it might be okay in another situation I need to have different Recievers for when the phone is on and when the phone has booted.

To summarize myquestions are :-

Why is RecieverHandler dealing with the Boot completed Intent and my BootReciever is never being called?

How can Intent data set before a reboot still be valid after a reboot?

Is their a way to delay any actions until the SMS sending abilities of a device are ready?

Answer (score 2):

You also need to set the permission to receive this intent.
 < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
For more details visit: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/